New Web application is styled by non-existent file
I've just created a new ASP.NET Core application.
Trying to sort out my styles, I see a number of styles that are affecting my site's appearance, and these styles are in a file called:
/UnitConversions.styles.css?v=UwuMegbk9MiovbtuJ5vTUyhs96HY9tiIc2YiWFg9YOM

Seems simple enough. But I don't have any file with this name.
So how do I edit the settings in the file?

Does the text "UnitConversions" exist anywhere in the application?  Such as in some bundling/minification/etc. operation that happens on build/deploy?

@David: Yes, it's the name of my application.

Ah, that makes much more sense then.  My current guess would still be related to bundling/minification.  If you examine the contents of this CSS in the browser's debugging tools, can you find a potentially unique style rule that can also be searched in the application?  That is, does this essentially contain the combined style rules of other CSS files in the application?  (I'm also going to try creating an empty project on my workstation now and see if I can get info from that.  It's been a while and project templates may have changed.)

The file is apparently created by Visual Studio. In addition, it adds a strange attribute to most of my elements. This is apparently related to ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation.
One way to deal with it is to disable this feature by adding the following line to the project file.
<ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>


Just found it in my test as well.  My project was MVC, so the link the template provided for me was: https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification  The "strange attribute" appears to be part of the build/deploy process as well, as the same (empty) attributes are added to elements on the page.  It appears to be a way of confining the styles to the specific page/layout/etc. with which they are associated.  (The "scoped CSS" in the project file you found.)

It's been part of Razor Pages since .NET 6: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/355/css-isolation-in-razor-pages

Try to locate the file in wwwroot folder, filename is:
UnitConversions.styles.css

And the rest which is:
?v=UwuMegbk9MiovbtuJ5vTUyhs96HY9tiIc2YiWFg9YOM

Is a querystring appended to url just to control the version of css file

Yes, I know that much. But the file does not exist. It appears to have been generated by Visual Studio.
